# JScrollPane - to JFrame or JPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans, jscrollpane

(using netbeans) 
So for my project I need to add a `JscrollPane` so that the user can see all of the `JTextArea` output, a piechart and the two buttons I have added. This is the code I have implementing the `JscrollPane`. However it is causing the program to no longer produce an output screen. My question is do I need to add the `JscrollPane` to the JPanel or to the JFrame and if so what am I doing wrong (tried to include as much of the code as I thought was relevant)

P.S Should I change from `Borderlayout` to a `Boxlayout`? Would that make a difference in terms of adding a jscroll?

```
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Portfolio Results");


        frame1.setSize(800,800);
       // frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);







       // output screen declartions 
       frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
       frame1.add(panel1,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
        area1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        panel1.add(area1,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JScrollPane scp1 = new JScrollPane(frame1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame1.add(scp1);

        //code for Pie chart and two button
         DefaultPieDataset piedata = new DefaultPieDataset();
         piedata.setValue("test", new Integer (100));
         JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("test", piedata,      true, true, true);

        PiePlot p = (PiePlot)chart.getPlot();
        ChartPanel testpan = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel1.add(testpan,BorderLayout.CENTER);



       JButton button= new JButton("SAVE");

      // button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
      // Listener listener = new Listener();
    //   button.addActionListener(this);
       panel1.add(button,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


       JButton pbutton=new JButton("Print");
       panel1.add(pbutton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should init the `JScrollPane` with the object you want to scroll through.

In your example, it seems the `JTextArea` is the object you want, so:

```
JScrollPane scp1 = new JScrollPane(area1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

From the `Oracle` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html):

> ```
>  JScrollPane(Component view)
> ```
>
> Creates a JScrollPane **that displays the contents of the specified component**, where both horizontal and
>   vertical scrollbars appear whenever the component's contents are
>   larger than the view.

Also, see this `Oracle` [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).